# Android - Looping Activity to Repeat MediaPlayer

Tags: android, loops, android-activity, media-player, imagebutton

I'm trying to create a soundboard for longer audio files and can't figure out how to stop an audio file and start it again without closing the activity. Let's say each audio file is one minute long. If I play the first audio file for 20 seconds and start the next audio file, the first stops playing and the second starts playing. However, if I click the first audio file again, the second stops playing and the first does not. I need help. This is driving me insane.

```
    bAudio1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bAudio1);
    bAudio2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bAudio2);

    mpAudio1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio1);
    mpAudio2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio2);

    bAudio1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(mpAudio1.isPlaying()) {
                            mpAudio1.stop();
                    } else {
                            if(mpAudio2.isPlaying()) { mpAudio2.stop(); }
                            mpAudio1.start();
                    }
            }
    });

    bAudio2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(mpAudio2.isPlaying()) {
                            mpAudio2.stop();
                    } else {
                            if(mpAudio1.isPlaying()) { mpAudio1.stop(); }
                            mpAudio2.start();
                    }
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button button1;
private Button button2;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        // play first audio clip and stop the second if playing
        if (mediaPlayer2 != null && mediaPlayer2.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer2.stop();
            mediaPlayer2.release();
            mediaPlayer2 = null;
        }
        mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song1);
        mediaPlayer1.start();
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        // play second audio clip and stop the first if playing
        if (mediaPlayer1 != null && mediaPlayer1.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer1.stop();
            mediaPlayer1.release();
            mediaPlayer1 = null;
        }
        mediaPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song2);
        mediaPlayer2.start();
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // stop the second if playing
    if (mediaPlayer2 != null && mediaPlayer2.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer2.stop();
        mediaPlayer2.release();
        mediaPlayer2 = null;
    }

    // stop the first if playing
    if (mediaPlayer1 != null && mediaPlayer1.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer1.stop();
        mediaPlayer1.release();
        mediaPlayer1 = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I took out .prepare() since I wasn't setting a data source, though you would need to include it if you decided to read the song from a file.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepare()  Also, I left out the logic to stop the song from the button that starts it.  That should probably be abstracted out to another button IMHO.